# ajax - request error with status code 200

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

From client side, I wanna send some data to server and receive some `<div>` tags which responding from `View` (another controller).

My ajax code looks like this:

```
var sortTopic = function () {
    var $list = [],
        $address = '',
        $formData = new FormData();

    /* do something here to set value to $list and $address */

    $formData.append('Category', $list);
    $formData.append('Address', $address);
    $formData.append('Tags', '[KM]');
    $formData.append('Skip', 0);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Topic/Sort',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.success) {
                $('.jumbotron').html(data.ex);
            } else {
                $('.jumbotron').html(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.status); //xhr.status: 200
        }
    });
};
```

In `TopicController`, action `Sort` was:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Sort(SortTopicViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        if (model.IsValidSortTopicModel())
        {
            return PartialView("../Home/_Timeline", new TopicMaster().Sort(model));
        }
        return Json(new { success = false, ex = "Invalid model." });
    }
    catch (Exception e) { return Json(new { success = false, ex = e.Message }); }
}
```

I'm sure that the `model` is valid and method `new TopicMaster().Sort(model)` was working fine (because I had put breakpoint to view the return data). And the partial view `_Timeline` is a partial view of `HomeController`.

My problem is: I don't understand why I get `error` with status code 200 in ajax:

`error: function (xhr) {
     alert(xhr.status); //xhr.status: 200
 }`

Can you explain to me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you told you receive `<div>` in response that is not json and you mention `dataType:"json"` in your ajax just remove it. this will solve your problem. error 200 occur when you did not get valid response which is you mention in ajax.

for mor information you can read it [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem. Can I ask you a sub-question? In server side, I wanna send to client an error message if the `model` is not valid. In my example, it's in line: `return Json(new { success = false, ex = "Invalid model." });`. So, is it working if I remove `dataType: "json"`?

Comment: yes that will work but after removing `dataType: "json"` you need to parse your response in json. and as you told you are receiving `<div>` then how you will identify that you are getting `html` or `json` in response.